# get value from tuple keys dictionary and sequential

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary

```
d = {(1,100) : 0.5 , (1,150): 0.7 ,(1,190) : 0.8, (2,100) : 0.5 , (2,120): 0.7 ,(2,150) : 0.8, (3,100) : 0.5 , (3,110): 0.7 ,(4,100) : 0.5 , (4,150): 0.7 ,(4,190) : 0.8,(5,100) : 0.5 , (5,150): 0.7}
list = [4,2,1,3,5]

for (k1,k2),k3 in d.items():
 for k1 in list :
   print(k1,k2 : ,k3)
```

I want get the value of dictionary sequential like my list for the key 1
and for key 2 I have diferrent score and count

```
(4,100) : 0.5 , (4,150): 0.7 ,(4,190) : 0.8,(2,100) : 0.5 , (2,120): 0.7 ,(2,150) : 0.8,(1,100) : 0.5 , (1,150): 0.7 ,(1,190) : 0.8,(3,100) : 0.5 , (3,110): 0.7 ,(5,100) : 0.5 , (5,150): 0.7}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted()` with the the values from the tuple as index in the list

```
d = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: lst.index(x[0][0])))
print(d)
```

Output

```
{(4, 100): 0.5, (4, 150): 0.7, (4, 190): 0.8, (2, 100): 0.5, (2, 120): 0.7, (2, 150): 0.8, (1, 100): 0.5, (1, 150): 0.7, (1, 190): 0.8, (3, 100): 0.5, (3, 110): 0.7, (5, 100): 0.5, (5, 150): 0.7}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
d = {(1, 100): 0.5,
     (1, 150): 0.5,
     (1, 190): 0.8,
     (2, 100): 0.5,
     (2, 120): 0.7,
     (2, 150): 0.8,
     (3, 100): 0.5,
     (3, 110): 0.7,
     (4, 100): 0.5,
     (4, 150): 0.7,
     (4, 190): 0.8,
     (5, 100): 0.5,
     (5, 150): 0.7}


lst = [4, 2, 1, 3, 5]

for key, k3 in d.items():

    print(f'({lst[key[0]-1]},{key[1]}) : ,{k3}')
```

Output:

```
(4,100) : ,0.5
(4,150) : ,0.5
(4,190) : ,0.8
(2,100) : ,0.5
(2,120) : ,0.7
(2,150) : ,0.8
(1,100) : ,0.5
(1,110) : ,0.7
(3,100) : ,0.5
(3,150) : ,0.7
(3,190) : ,0.8
(5,100) : ,0.5
(5,150) : ,0.7
```

Comment: i don't want to get result like that , to many useless result , like your result get looping of k2, thanks for you help